# Why did Jane Chapman move to Monterey?

Tags: plot-explanation, big-little-lies

In *Big Little Lies*, we have Jane Chapman, a single mother of Ziggy, who moves to Monterey from her parents place (I don't remember which).

Throughout the season, while Ziggy is painted as a bully by the students and parents, we are shown parents statements about the fact that Jane might be hiding her intentions of moving to Monterey.

There's a scene in the coffee shop where the owner asks Jane about this reason to move but Ziggy cuts in to say "good culture and facilities to bring up your kid in is all you are going to get".

It is later revealed that

> Jane was raped by Celeste's husband, Perry, who's also violent with Celeste.

Jane doesn't know him, doesn't seem to know his whereabouts and hasn't seen him before the climax of S01.

So why did Jane move to Monterey? Do the book give some clue about this?

Comment: I haven't read the book, but the wiki page for it does show some instances where things are a bit different & doesn't indicate that it's version of Jane "moved" from somewhere else. The thing I noticed about how the TV series is written is that it is full of misdirection and/or supposition that doesn't ever get answered in order to generate suspense.

Comment: Things like Celeste's father are touched on in one season of season 2, but never again. A glimpse into Mary Louis past is given, but no real proof about what all exactly happened and/or if Perry was the way he was before or after the incident. The Detective's beef is also never realized. Madeline has brothers she never talks about, etc. IMO one reason I think Jane came there besides wanting a better future for Ziggy was because she needed to get away from her parents, because for whatever reason, she could not tell them about what happened, as Maddie is the first one she tells...